# Loop through array and render multiple instances of a child component with that data with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component called ListContainer which contains a child component called ListItem. I need ListItem to be called for every item in an array called nameArray, and for the ListItem's name to be populated from the values in this array.

```
export const ListItem = (props) => {
  return <h2>Name: { props.name }</h2>;
};

export const ListContainer = (props) => {
  const nameArray = [
    {
      name: "john",
      age: "29"
    },
    {
      name: "james",
      age: "21"
    }
  ];
  return (
      <div>
      { this.nameArray.map(function(item) {
          return (
            <ListItem name={ item.name } />
          )
      }) }
      </div>
    );
};
```

From looking at the docs I think I need to use the map function, but im confused as to how it works in JSX.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to reference a local variable created in the render function, so remove the `this` from `this.nameArray.map`

```
{ nameArray.map( (item, i) => <ListItem key={i} name={ item.name } /> )}
```

Also your react component here is an inline stateless component. Its just a regular function with no react `this` context. aka you dont have `this.props` or `this.state`. you just have `props`. When you want to access props you only type props instead of this.props